# How to send a file from client side, performing an action and sending it back to the client side from the server in java socket programming

Tags: java, sockets, socket.io, tcpclient, tcpserver

I have written a code in java for sending a file from the client to server. The server side will perform an operation on the file and send it back to the client side. I have done it upto the point of performing the action on server side but the file is not received back on the client side. here is the code for reference

client side:

```
private void receiveFileBack() throws IOException {


int bytesRead;
int port; 

ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
// ServerSocket    serverSocketx = new ServerSocket(0);
//port = serverSocketx.getLocalPort();
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
while (true) {
Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
System.out.print("accepted connection"+clientSocket);
InputStream in = clientSocket.getInputStream();

DataInputStream clientData = new DataInputStream(in);

String fileName = clientData.readUTF();

System.out.print(fileName+"..........");
File f =new File("serverOut\\"+fileName);
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("serverOut\\"+fileName);
long size = clientData.readLong();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
while (size > 0 && (bytesRead = clientData.read(buffer, 0,
(int)Math.min(buffer.length, size))) != -1) {

serverStatus.append("Reading file..\n");
output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

size -= bytesRead;

}
//  clientSocket.close();
// Closing the FileOutputStream handle  
output.close();
output.flush();
}
}
```

server side:

```
public void sendFileBack(String fileName)
throws UnknownHostException,FileNotFoundException, IOException {
Socket sock = new Socket("192.168.0.103", 13267);
String tmpName=fName.replace(".mcrl2", ".lps");
File myFile = new File("out" + "\\" +tmpName );
byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile)
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis)
//bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);  

DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis)
dis.readFully(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();

//Sending file name and file size to the server  
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
dos.writeUTF(myFile.getName());
dos.writeLong(mybytearray.length);
dos.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
dos.flush();

//Sending file data to the server  
os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
os.flush();
console.append("\n\n Output file transfered successfully \n \n");


//Closing socket  
sock.close();
}




//this is receiving file method back from server
```

stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
abp.lpsaccepted connectionSocket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=53150,localport=4444]Jan 12, 2014 10:05:31 PM mcrl2.MainFrame$41 run
SEVERE: null
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:203)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(DataInputStream.java:337)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:589)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
at mcrl2.MainFrame.receiveFileBack(MainFrame.java:1353)
at mcrl2.MainFrame.access$4200(MainFrame.java:48)
at mcrl2.MainFrame$41.run(MainFrame.java:1402)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 40 seconds)
```

Any help will be appreciated. please tell me where am I going wrong.
Thanks in advance

Comment: looks like the right approach to me. any exceptions or stacktrace??

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
abp.lpsaccepted connectionSocket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=53150,localport=4444]Jan 12, 2014 10:05:31 PM mcrl2.MainFrame$41 run
SEVERE: null
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
 at

Comment: java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:203)
 at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(DataInputStream.java:337)
 at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:589)
 at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
 at mcrl2.MainFrame.receiveFileBack(MainFrame.java:1353)
 at mcrl2.MainFrame.access$4200(MainFrame.java:48)
 at mcrl2.MainFrame$41.run(MainFrame.java:1402)

Comment: please edit your question and include the full stack trace over there.

Comment: @Ashish... included in the question. please reply ASAP

Comment: can you point out MainFrame.java:1353, MainFrame.java:48 and MainFrame.java:1402. without looking thoroughly, I wouldnt be able to help

Comment: I have found the problem area.
when i try to send the file back after receiving it.the client code mentioned above do not have any file to send as the file appears after compilation .
is there any way to delay the call of file send method until file generation in the particular directory.

Comment: what im trying to say is that as the file is being generated at the back end, the code stops (sleeps) at a particular line and then after sometime, goes to the next line? I guess there some function like delay or sleep?

Comment: you could invoke sleep method of Thread class . something like this: Thread.sleep(int milliseconds);

Comment: thread.sleep is not working. it works fine when the file of same name already exists in the folder from where we have to send the file back to the client side.

Comment: I am thinking you are making things way more complicated that they should be. In this case Thread.sleep was not a good idea anyways. I am assuming you have already looked at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563203/transferring-file-through-socket-in-java

Comment: I dont see how the link you gave is relevant to my problem. let me explain it again to you. i send a file from the client side. The file compiles on the server side and saves in an out folder. The server has to send the file back but it doesn't because it cannot find the file of that name. Now when I re-run the code, the file already exists in the out folder, so the output file is received successfully on the client side. Get my point?

Comment: You are not using the same port, the connection is `null` ?